# Do medal effects stack?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

In *The Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword* do the effects of the various medals stack? For example, if I equip the `Treasure Medal` with the `Cursed Medal` will that give the effects of both, granting much more treasure drops? Same for the `Rupee Medal` and `Cursed Medal`.

Comment: Doh, I was setting up an experiment to test this all out.  Was planning on doing it in the **Waterfall Cave**.  I'm at the end of the game and that cave is completely cleared out of monsters... so much for that.  It will be a PITA to do this at other locations.  Perhaps it's something you might want to test yourself (or anyone else wanting to pick up on).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe you you guys are wrong. Many medals do stack. The 2 life medals will give two extra heart containers. Also, the cursed medal does not seem to nullify static effects. With the cursed medal in your bag you still get an extra heart container from a life medal, you still get extra ammo from ammo bags, and the bug medal still works with the cursed medal as well. Also other items like ammo bags stack if you have more than one.

All this seems to point to medals and other items stacking. Even with the cursed medal.

Comment: That's a good point about the Cursed Medal, I forgot about that (again).  You cannot _use_ items in your pouch but their passive effects still apply.  I guess it is still possible to run the full tests with the Cursed Medal.

Answer (score 2):

The Cursed Medal doesn't nullify anything, just won't let you OPEN your pouch.  All items in your pouch are still in effect (you'll still get a higher Bomb and Arrow count, you'll get your extra hearts from the Life and Heart Medals, and the Potion Medal works too).

Answer (score 1):

The cursed medal nullifies the effects of all other items and medals in you pouches. So stacking the abilities of two medals with similar effect at the same time is, in fact, impossible.

Comment: That's a good point about the Cursed Medal, I forgot about that.

Comment: To my knowledge, the only other medal in the game that there exists more than one of is the one that increases your number of heart containers by one, and both of those apply at once.

Comment: Wrong. there is a medal called life medal that increases your total number of hearts by 1 heart container. There is one called heart medal, this one makes it more likely for hearts to appear randomly when you defeat an enemy, cut grass or break something. They don't have the same effects.
I don't know why, but many guides have them mixed up as the same, while they really aren't

Comment: There are 2 Life Medals in the game: One is in Beedle's shop and the other is in a Goddess Chest late in the game.  And no, I'm not confusing it with the Heart Medal that you get quite early in the game.