# In Hero Mode, is a Heart Medal almost ineffective in dungeons? What about with two?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

I'm playing through Hero Mode. After I started the Lanayru Mining Facility, I left, got one of the Heart Medals, and returned for the rest of the dungeon.

I destroyed three or four *dozen* barrels and pots after equipping the Heart Medal, and in that whole time, I got only two hearts, plus one each from two Spumes, for a total of four.

I didn't even get hearts from the pots that were previously guaranteed to have hearts. I didn't even get hearts from the pots in the boss chamber!

If a Heart Medal gets me only four hearts per dungeon, I think I'd rather leave it with Peatrice and carry something else. Is this typical? And when I get the other Heart Medal later on, will carrying both render them any more effective than carrying the one?

Comment: You should sit on a stool or go to bed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The chance for hearts with the **Heart Medal** is greatly reduced.  Breakables that you know had guaranteed hearts (e.g., pots in boss battles) in them will *not* have hearts in them (AFAIK).

I would strongly recommend playing through the game with the **Heart Medal** equipped.  Sure, you're not going to find as many hearts still, but you're getting them.  And in Hero Mode, you're going to need all the help you can get.  You are most likely going to have two hearts at some point in the game and a hit means instant death or using one of your bottled fairies.  If you can find a heart to bring your total to three, you just gave yourself an extra hit to take before being forced to use your fairy.

Besides, *any* heart you find could be upgraded to a fairy if you keep around **Glittering Spores**.  They are really a lifesaver, especially in this mode and totally worth keeping.

Comment: I don't have an answer for your second question, but there is already an existing question on that: [Do medal effects stack?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38919/do-medal-effects-stack)  You'll want to keep an eye on that question for that answer.

Comment: I've played further through the game at this point, and I find that my chances of getting hearts from cut grass is much greater than that from breaking pots or barrels, including in dungeons. But I'm not sure whether it's just because grass generally comes in greater quantities, or if the probability per tuft is actually higher than per pot.

Answer (score -1):

It would most likely stack the effects for having two, I got my first from Beedle, and then got another from a goddess cube.  I have found double the hearts then usual.  I think your game is facing a common bug/glitch.  I wish you best of luck for this bug to go away.